# How to refresh List Adapter from another class?

Tags: java, android

I wonder if anybody could help me with my code. I have a ListView which lists Devices from database. Each device has a status which is represented with colored icon. Each device has also bunch of buttons to start/stop/etc the device and that works (after logout and login icon changed color). What I want to do is somehow refresh this list so icons color is up-to-date. Thanks in advance!

ListAdapter.java:

```java
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] deviceName;
    private final String[] ip;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public ListAdapter(Activity context, String[] deviceName, String[] ip, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, deviceName);

        this.context = context;
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.imgid = imgid;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

        TextView titleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView subtitleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        Button startBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        Button stopBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        final String URL3 = "http://damiangozdzi.nazwa.pl/pact-dev/sendstatus.php";


        titleText.setText(deviceName[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        subtitleText.setText(ip[position]);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Device has been started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SenderStatus s = new SenderStatus(getContext(), URL3, Integer.toString(position +1), "3");
                s.execute();
                //I tried to refresh my list from here but nothing worked
            }
        });

        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Device has been stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SenderStatus s = new SenderStatus(getContext(), URL3, Integer.toString(position +1), "1");
                s.execute();

            }
        });


        return rowView;
    }


}
```

User.java:

```java
public class User extends Fragment {
    private ListView list;
    private Button startBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;

    private String[] deviceName ={};
    private String[] ip ={};


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);

        Devices d = Devices.getInstance();
        String s = d.getString();
        String[][] all = getDevices(s);

        deviceName = all[0];
        ip = all[1];
        String[] pre_imgid = all[2];
        int x = pre_imgid.length;
        Integer[] imgid = new Integer[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            switch(pre_imgid[i]){
                case "0":
                    imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_szary; break;
                case "1":
                    imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_czerwony; break;
                case "2":
                    imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_pomarancz; break;
                case "3":
                    imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_zielony; break;
                default:
                    imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_niebieski; break;
            }
        }


        ListAdapter adapter=new ListAdapter(getActivity(), deviceName, ip, imgid);
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.plcsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    public String[][] getDevices(String s){

        char c = '{';
        int count = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {    if(s.charAt(i) == c)
            count++;
        }

        String[][] all =  new String[3][count];

        if (s == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "s is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    all[0][i] = obj.getString("address");
                    all[1][i] = obj.getString("name");
                    all[2][i] = Integer.toString(obj.getInt("status"));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return all;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to update from the Fragment

Comment: create a method inside the Adapter to update the data (in your case the arrays)

Comment: I would like to update simultaneously with pressing the button startBtn.setOnClickListener, but if you have better idea..

Comment: The method to update data is one and it should be inside the adapter. Then you call it where you want.

Comment: You can make `Timer` which will be updating your adapter (every 30 sec or minute). I've done something similar once, but I was removing items from adapter after given time.

Comment: I've made it inside `Recycler` Adapter, but the problem was that when item wasn't visible on the screen, it wasn't removed, but I've changed it to `setText()` of `TextView` to "Finished" and it worked fine. So if you just want to change fields it should do. I'm sorry for two comments, but I couldn't edit previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Create a method inside the adapter that receives your `deviceName, ip, imgid` as parameteres. Then you just need to call it when you click on the button.

On the adapter:

```
public void refreshData(String[] deviceName, String[] ip, Integer[] imgid){
    this.deviceName = deviceName;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.imgid = imgid;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then on the click button:

```
adapter.refreshData(yourDeviceNameVariable, yourIpVariable, yourImdidVariable);
```

I suggest you to put this code inside a method, where the deviceName, the ip and the imdid variable are global variables, and you call that method on button click, before refreshing the adapter.

```
Devices d = Devices.getInstance();
String s = d.getString();
String[][] all = getDevices(s);

deviceName = all[0];
ip = all[1];
String[] pre_imgid = all[2];
int x = pre_imgid.length;
Integer[] imgid = new Integer[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    switch(pre_imgid[i]){
        case "0":
            imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_szary; break;
        case "1":
            imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_czerwony; break;
        case "2":
            imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_pomarancz; break;
        case "3":
            imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_zielony; break;
        default:
            imgid[i] = R.drawable.large_circle_niebieski; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I put the refresh method into the ListAdapter and when I try to call it in onClick, it says "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". But when I try to change the declaration to "public static void refreshData..." everything goes to red and says it's static and suggests "Make non-static". What can I do now?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just realized that the onClick methos are inside the adapter, and not in the activity. So I suggest that you inside the onClick change the variable to the state you need/want, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Since you have the position, you just need to get the variable on the position x from the variable you need to change

Comment: It worked :) I did as you wrote. Added:
                imgid[position] = R.drawable.large_circle_zielony;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
in my OnClick and it refreshes. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This is something you need to workaround. I will be giving you the points to change but you need to update your code.

In onclicklistener of both start/stop you need to get the selected object manually and update there data, where by the view will be updated on the fly.

Here, you have to do something like, settag() to your parent layout with object from the list, i see there is multiple list, use the object of the list where you are updating the view.

Eg: `// your parentlayout.setTag(devicename[position])`

In onclicklistner, you need to get this object

Eg: `// get your object from settag:- DeviceName dobj = (DeviceName) view.getTag()`

Further:

```
dobj.updateview, // something your logic of updating view.
```

that's it, you are good to go but the problem is your class design.

Suggestion:

1. Create one more model class where your deviname and ip also the data/field you so want to edit/update in onclicklistener
2. Try to use list/map, preferably list to pass to adapter.